# Looking for a microcontroller for embedded OS

Tags: embedded-systems, osx, microcontroller

I'm looking for an MCU with development board on which I can build a small embedded OS.

I'm looking for something along these lines:

- At least single digit MBs of EEPROM or flash.
- About 1MB or so SRAM.
- Single core
- Flat memory map, no cache
- Fast enough to achieve 10-20 fps on a low-resolution display
- Von Neumann architecture

Any help would be appreciated

Edit1: no upper price limit

Edit2: I ended up settling on the PIC32MZ2048EFG064, it has 2MB flash, 0.5MB sram, runs at 200MHz, it's not von Neumann but it does allow you to execute from sram and write to flash during execution.

Comment: Is it safe for posters to assume you have no upper price limit?